# Magento responsive design - Horizontal product categories

Tags: css, magento, mobile, responsive

Does anyone know how to make category callouts scroll horizontally in responsive design? Right now they're stacking all my products. I want to take the category call outs on our homepage that generally hold 10-20 products, and keep that same horizontal scroll feature on mobile. Instead it takes the 5 products and stacks them for each of the call outs I have. I assume this is a css change, but I'm not exactly sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any javascript plugins like owl Carousel or Slick Slider to make a horizontal scroll widget on your homepage. Refer the link below to get an idea

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html